# Unity3D: APK file missing

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, sdk, apk

Every time I try and build my game, I am unable to find the APK file anywhere, I did however found the APK file in my recent folder, but it doesn't show up in the respective folders I initially selected or allows me to copy and paste the APK file into my Android device.

I don't even get any errors when the game is built (in fact, I get a message in my console stating that my build was successful) so I am confused to why my APK file is not showing up.

It happened after I recently updated my unity 5.6 to unity 2018.3.1 due to Oracle JDK is no longer free for commercial use and unity 2018.3 uses OpenJDK (I am using AdoptOpenJDK/JDK-12.0.1.12-hotspot). Once unity was installed, I didn't receive any errors only a few warnings within a few scripts (which was only a minor problem and I could solve easily).

However, when I go to player settings, I get this one warning: "failed to get available Android API levels. Make sure your Android SDK tools version is 25 or higher and you have an internet connection."

I made sure that my minimum API level is Android 8.0 'Oreo' (API level 26) and the target API level is Android 8.1 'Oreo' (API level 27), I also uninstall Android studio and reinstalled.

I even went as far as deleting all folders inside build tools and platforms from (appdata>local>android>sdk>buildtools) & (appdata>local>android>sdk>platforms) and updating the files for continuing the build.

However, all the methods I've tried have not to work, so I'm asking for help here. Please, does anyone know why is my APK file not appearing at all? Thank you in advance, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

this solution helped me if Are you using the r22 of android SDK, if so, Google decided to move the aapt.exe from tools directory to build-tools//aapt.exe
A quick solution for this is co copy the aapt.exe file from build-tools and paste as shortcut on tools directory. Keep the shortcut name as aapt.exe

another solution is to download jdk(1.8 version is prefered)from oracle site ["http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html"]and set it instead of the build-in jdk form the project preferences then reboot

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried out what you said about copying the aapt.exe file from the build-tools and paste it in the tools folder, however when it finished building I still got the same result.

Comment: I would like to use oracle jdk, however, it is not free for commercial use anymore.